# Order list in recycler view, Android Studio, Kotlin

Tags: sorting, arraylist

I am trying to order the results downloaded from Firestore.

I download and print the result and they are out of order, after ordering them I bring them again and they print in order of date, but the result in the recycler view doesn't update.

This is the code I use to order the list, originally it is an array list of hash map but I convert it to a mutable list so I can order it and then back to an array list.

```
val newList = messagesInfo.sortedWith(compareBy {
                    it.dateC }).toMutableList()

                messagesInfo = newList as ArrayList<MessagesPost>

                println("Tony the date new list array is $messagesInfo")
                messagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out.

by moving my submit list down under the reassignment of the array.

```
  val newList = messagesInfo.sortedWith(compareBy {
                it.dateC }).toMutableList().reversed()

            messagesInfo = newList as ArrayList<MessagesPost>

            messagesAdapter.submitList(messagesInfo)
            messagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```